# how can I divide an EJB 2 session bean

Tags: java, ejb, ejb-2.x, session-bean

I have some session beans that are becomming quite complex so I want to find a way to divide them, but I still need to treat the divided parts as session beans.

Comment: You mean, your bean class has a large number of methods ?

Comment: Yes, indeed this is the case.

Comment: Is this bean a stateless session bean ?

Comment: Stateful session bean.

Comment: Does all of those methods are exposed as public methods via remote/local interfaces or there are some utility methods as well ?

Comment: All methods are public via remote/local interfaces, no utility methods.

Answer (score 0):

Why dont u try using inheritance and put sme methods in super call and expose child class as session bean.g